# Strong orientation graph algorithm with Robbins' theorem

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I've been asked a question that goes something like this:

> Using depth-first search and Robbins' theorem, design and analyze an efficient algorithm to construct a strong orientation of a given undirected graph G. If none exist, output a bridge in G.

Now, I can prove Robbins' theorem easily, which states that a graph is strongly orientable if and only if it has no bridges (i.e. it is 2-edge-connected). The example given to me is similar to what's given in Robbins' 1939 paper describing his eponymous theorem with the traffic problem and one-way streets.

Can we do something as follows:

1. run DFS from root vertex r
2. orient all tree edges away from r
3. orient all back edges towards r

I'm not sure how to prove that this creates a strong orientation, though.